# Can a model for a resampled time series be useful for modeling the original time series?

Tags: time-series

Say we have a time series $x_i, i=1, \dots$. If it is hard to model, then is it possibly acceptable to model the resampled one $y_i := x_{ik}, i = 1, \dots$ for some fixed natural number $k$? (Assume no special requirement or restriction, just a general case.)

If I have a model for $y_i$'s, can that be helpful in modeling the original $x_i$'s, and how? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a model for the fixed sample of Y's, you can use convergence properties to make inference about the X's. This assumes that your Y's are a random sample of the X's.

It's difficult to make really broad and universally applicable statements about this. The idea is that if your sample is random, then your results from the sample apply to the population because your model converges (at least) in probability, if not in distribution*.

--

*There are several different kinds of convergence: in distribution, in probability and convergence to a constant. [See the advanced stats [book](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Mathematical_statistics.html?id=8poZAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) by Bickel and Doksum on this  Appendix A, Section 14. Unless you have a strong handle on analysis, this is a terrible book to read because you will not understand most of it.]

Comment: By "resample" here, I mean take one every $k$, not actually random resampling

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you're taking every k, because the X's are presumably random. If the X's aren't random, you have to know something about the non-random nature of the X's so you can mimic it with how you're sampling the Y's. Proxy or alias modelling (for lack of a better term) is common in some animal studies like fish, where it's difficult to measure what you're after, so you have to use a proxy. I'm not sure if this is the kind of thing that you're looking for. To properly answer this, you need to narrow down the field a bit.